# Cannot create a aqueduct project

Tags: flutter, dart, aqueduct

This is the error I get when I run `aqueduct create project`. Aqueduct is activated.

```
-- Aqueduct CLI Version: 3.3.0+1
*** Uncaught error
    Bad state: No element
  **** Stacktrace
  * #0      ListMixin.firstWhere (dart:collection/list.dart:150:5)
  * #1      CLIAqueductGlobal.aqueductPackageRef (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:342:10)
  * #2      CLIAqueductGlobal.templateDirectory (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:347:12)
  * #3      CLIAqueductGlobal.getTemplateLocation (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:351:12)
  * #4      CLITemplateCreator.handle (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:51:27)
  * #5      CLICommand.process (package:aqueduct/src/cli/command.dart:159:20)
  * <asynchronous suspension>
  * #6      CLICommand.process (package:aqueduct/src/cli/command.dart:135:12)
  * #7      main (file:///C:/Users/dos/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/aqueduct-3.3.0+1/bin/aqueduct.dart:9:27)
  * #8      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
  * #9      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
  ****
```

what must to do?

Comment: I have same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: yes but i deleted all files about dart and flutter and the setup of vs code and android studio the n download aqueduct first install dart 2.7.0 then install dart then try

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all files about dart and flutter and the setup of vs code and android studio the n download aqueduct first install dart 2.7.0 then install dart then try